# If All the doctrines outside Vedas are useless and False, Why is a Mahavidya Goddess like Tara pleased only when worshipped through an unvedic Achara?

Tags: tantra, devi, shaktism, dasha-mahavidya

Manusmriti says -

> 12.95. All those traditions (smriti) and those despicable systems of philosophy, which are not based on the Veda, produce no reward after
> death; for they are declared to be founded on Darkness.
>
> 12.96. All those (doctrines), differing from the (Veda), which spring up and (soon) perish, are worthless and false

But In the Tantras, It is said that Goddess Tara, One of the Mahavidya Goddesses is pleased only through Chinachara, The Achara Taught by Buddharoopi Vishnu(An consequently veda-viruddha)

Citing the Anecdote of Vasistha's worship of Tara from [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shakti-and-shakta/d/doc210195.html)-

> According to the account of the Brahmayāmala, Vasiṣṭha complaining of
> his ill-success was told to go to the Blue Mountains (Nīlāchala) and
> worship Parameśvarī near Kāmākhya (Kamrup in Assam). **He was told that
> Viṣṇu in the form of Buddha (Buddharūpā) alone knew this worship
> according to Cīnācāra.**
>
> Devī said,
>
> **“without Cīnācāra you cannot please Me. Go to Viṣṇu who is
> Udbodharūpī(illumined) and worship Me according to the Ācāra taught by
> Him.”**

The story further continues-

> Vasiṣṭha then went to Viṣṇu in the country Mahācīna, which is by the
> side of the Himālaya (Himavatpārśve), a country inhabited by great
> Sādhakas and thousands of beautiful and youthful women whose hearts
> were gladdened with wine, and whose minds were blissful with enjoyment
> (Vilāsa). They were adorned with clothes which inspired love
> (Śringāravesha) and the movement of their hips made tinkle their
> girdles of little bells. Free of both fear and prudish shame they
> enchanted the world. They surround Īśvara and are devoted to ths
> worship of Devī.
>
> Vasiṣṭha wondered greatly when he saw Him in the form of Buddha
> (Buddharūpī) with eyes drooping from wine.
>
> **“What” he said,“is Viṣṇu doing in His Buddha form? This way (Ācāra) is opposed to
> Veda (Vedavādaviruddha). I do not approve of it (Asammato mama).”**
>
> Whilst so thinking, he heard a voice coming from the ether saying,
>
> “Oh thou who art devoted to good acts, think not like this. **This
> Āhāra is of excellent result in the Sādhanā of Tārinī. She is not
> pleased with anything which is the contrary of this. If thou dost wish
> to gain Her grace speedily, then worship Her according to Cīnācāra.”**
>
> Hearing this voice, Vasiṣṭha’s hairs stood on end and he fell to the
> ground. Being filled with exceeding joy he prayed to Viṣṇu in the form
> of Buddha (Buddharūpa). Buddha, who had taken wine, seeing him was
> greatly pleased and said, “Why have you come here?” Vasiṣṭha bowing to
> Buddha told him of his worship of Tārinī. **Buddha who is Hari and
> full of knowledge (Tattvajñāna) spoke to him of the five Makāras (M:
> that is, the five commencing with the letter M or Madya, or wine and
> so forth) which are in Cīnācāra (Majnānam Cīnācārādiāranam) saying
> that this should not be disclosed (a common injunction as regards this
> ritual and renders it from the opponents’ standpoint suspect).**
>
> “By practising it thou shalt not again sink into the ocean of being.
> It is full of knowledge of the Essence (Tattvajñāna) and gives
> immediate liberation (Mukti).”
>
> He then goes on to explain a principal feature of this cult, namely,
> **its freedom from the ritual rules of the ordinary worship above which the Sādhaka has risen. It is mental worship. In it bathing,
> purification, Japa, and ceremonial worship is by the mind only.** (No
> outward acts are necessary; the bathing end so forth is in the mind
> and not in actual water, as is the, case in lower and less advanced
> worship.) **There are no rules aa to auspicious and inauspicious
> times, or as to what should be done by day and by night. Nothing is
> pure or impure (there is no ritual defect of impurity) nor prohibition
> against the taking of food.** Devi should be worshipped even though
> the worshipper has had his food, and even though the place be unclean.
> Woman who is Her image should be worshipped (Pūjanam striyah) and
> never should any injury be done to her (Strīveśo naiva kartavyah).

Now the question lies that if everything outside Vedas are useless and false, why is a Mahavidya Goddess Pleased when worshipped through a vedaviruddha achara?

Comment: Vedas are useful. Outside philosophies might be too. What if Manusmirit is useless? Your question is useless unless the authority of manusmiriti is established.

Comment: @User29449 The orthodox stand disagrees with your opinion that any philosophy outside the vedas can be useful too

Comment: I don't care about *any-dox. Vedas don't say it themselves. It is ONLY if you take Manusmiriti *above* vedas to validate it, otherwise your question is meaningless.

Comment: @User29449 yeah you liberals definitely don't have authority on whether Manu is legitimate or not.

Comment: @Haridasa Thank you for the personal attack. The answer to the question was just simple - Tantras do give authority to Vedas but not Manusmriti. This is why they don't get invalidated. But now you already attributed tantras to *liberalism* too, so I take it as a compliment.

Comment: @User29449 I wasn't attacking you, but you're answer did state Manu doesn't have authority. "What if Manusmirit is useless?"

Comment: @Haridasa IF YOU KNOW, Manu has **any** authority in tantras or agamas then write one answer and NOT personally attack people who state facts that you don't like.

Comment: @User29449 I am not personally attacking you, but your view seems liberal no?

Comment: @user34086 yes, kalika purana and devi bhagavata mention chinachara/tara as avaidika due to curse